# Rcpp - speeding up nested list operations with larger lists

Tags: r, rcpp

**Rcpp List Operations**

*note: this post has been edited based on initial feedback*

Rcpp and list operations - that is a popular topic here. Copy vs shallow copy of objects inside the lists really matters when objects are large. I am illustrating this with a minimal example below.

**Question**

Any additional ideas to speed up accessing nested loop elements?

**Setup**

First, let me introduce the data structure: A nested list, where the inner lists contain a vector and a matrix. One nested lists will be populated with lists containing small vectors/matrices, the other with big ones. This structure is consistent with many hierarchical models, where some kind of computation is done at the *i* level, for each *i*.

```
outerlistsize=100

vectorsize=1000

outerlist_smalldata=list()

for(ll in 1:outerlistsize){
  outerlist_smalldata[[ll]]=list()
  outerlist_smalldata[[ll]]$a=rnorm(vectorsize)
  outerlist_smalldata[[ll]]$b=matrix(rnorm(vectorsize*4),vectorsize,4)
}


vectorsize=100000
outerlist_bigdata=list()

for(ll in 1:outerlistsize){
  outerlist_bigdata[[ll]]=list()
  outerlist_bigdata[[ll]]$a=rnorm(vectorsize)
  outerlist_bigdata[[ll]]$b=matrix(rnorm(vectorsize*4),vectorsize,4)
}
```

### R

Let’s say we want to do a simple matrix multiplication for each of these lists. An R version of that is simple:

```
rfun=function(outerlist){
  outerlistsize=length(outerlist)
  outmatrix=matrix(NA,outerlistsize,4)

  for(ll in 1:outerlistsize){
    outmatrix[ll,]= outerlist[[ll]]$a %*% outerlist[[ll]]$b
  }
}
```

### Rcpp

Now let’s do it in Rcpp. Different versions:

- Vanilla Armadillo (objects are copied)
- Armadillo with shallow copy
- Armadillo with shallow copy and fixed dimensions
- Vanilla struct
- Struct with initial shallow copy (but eventually struct creation copies objects)

**Armadillo**

```
    #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec cf_copy_i(Rcpp::List inlist){
  vec avec =  Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(inlist["a"]);
  mat bmat =  Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(inlist["b"]);
  return( vectorise(trans(trans(avec) * bmat)));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat cf_copy(Rcpp::List outerlist){
  int outerlistsize =outerlist.size();
  mat outmatrix(outerlistsize,4);
  for(int ll=0; ll<outerlistsize; ll++){
    Rcpp::List innerlist = outerlist[ll];
    outmatrix.row(ll)= trans(cf_copy_i(innerlist));
  }
  return(outmatrix);
}
```

**Shallow copy**

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec cf_shallow_i(const Rcpp::List & inlist){
  NumericVector ave =  inlist["a"];
  NumericMatrix bma =  inlist["b"];
  arma::vec avec(ave.begin(), ave.size(), false);
  arma::mat bmat(bma.begin(), bma.rows(), bma.cols(), false);
  return( vectorise(trans(trans(avec) * bmat)));
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat cf_shallow(const Rcpp::List & outerlist){
  int outerlistsize =outerlist.size();
  mat outmatrix(outerlistsize,4);
  for(int ll=0; ll<outerlistsize; ll++){
    Rcpp::List innerlist = outerlist[ll];
    outmatrix.row(ll)= trans(cf_shallow_i(innerlist));
  }
  return(outmatrix);
}
```

**Shallow copy fixed dims**

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec cf_shallowstrict_i(const Rcpp::List & inlist){
  NumericVector ave =  inlist["a"];
  NumericMatrix bma =  inlist["b"];
  arma::vec avec(ave.begin(), ave.size(), false, true);
  arma::mat bmat(bma.begin(), bma.rows(), bma.cols(), false, true);
  return( vectorise(trans(trans(avec) * bmat)));
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat cf_shallowstrict(const Rcpp::List & outerlist){
  int outerlistsize =outerlist.size();
  mat outmatrix(outerlistsize,4);
  for(int ll=0; ll<outerlistsize; ll++){
    Rcpp::List innerlist = outerlist[ll];
    outmatrix.row(ll)= trans(cf_shallowstrict_i(innerlist));
  }
  return(outmatrix);
}
```

**Struct**

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec cf_nolist_i(const vec & avec, const mat & bmat){
  vec outvec= vectorise(trans(trans(avec) * bmat));
  return(outvec);
}


struct stuff{
  vec a;
  mat b;
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat cf_struct(const Rcpp::List & outerlist){
  int outerlistsize =outerlist.size();
  std::vector<stuff> list_vector;
  stuff listi_struct;
  List listi;

  for(int ij=0; ij<outerlistsize; ij++){
    listi = outerlist[ij];
    listi_struct.a = as<vec>(listi["a"]);
    listi_struct.b = as<mat>(listi["b"]);
    list_vector.push_back(listi_struct);  
  }

  mat outmatrix(outerlistsize,4);
  for(int ll=0; ll<outerlistsize; ll++){
    outmatrix.row(ll)= trans(cf_nolist_i(list_vector[ll].a, list_vector[ll].b));
  }
  return(outmatrix);
}
```

**Struct shallow**

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat cf_structshallow(const Rcpp::List & outerlist){
  int outerlistsize =outerlist.size();
  std::vector<stuff> list_vector;
  stuff listi_struct;
  List listi;

  for(int ij=0; ij<outerlistsize; ij++){
    listi = outerlist[ij];
     NumericVector ave =  listi["a"];
     NumericMatrix bma =  listi["b"];
     arma::vec avec(ave.begin(), ave.size(), false, true);
     arma::mat bmat(bma.begin(), bma.rows(), bma.cols(), false, true);
    listi_struct.a = avec;
    listi_struct.b = bmat;
    list_vector.push_back(listi_struct);  
  }

  mat outmatrix(outerlistsize,4);
  for(int ll=0; ll<outerlistsize; ll++){
    outmatrix.row(ll)= trans(cf_nolist_i(list_vector[ll].a, list_vector[ll].b));
  }
  return(outmatrix);
}
```

### Speed comparison

for small data ...

```
library(rbenchmark)
smd=outerlist_smalldata
bgd=outerlist_bigdata

bench_small=benchmark(rfun(smd),cf_copy(smd),cf_shallow(smd),cf_shallowstrict(smd),cf_struct(smd),cf_structshallow(smd), order="relative")
print(bench_small[,1:4])

##                    test replications elapsed relative
## 3       cf_shallow(smd)          100    0.03    1.000
## 4 cf_shallowstrict(smd)          100    0.03    1.000
## 2          cf_copy(smd)          100    0.08    2.667
## 1             rfun(smd)          100    0.14    4.667
## 6 cf_structshallow(smd)          100    0.39   13.000
## 5        cf_struct(smd)          100    0.40   13.333
```

... and big data

```
##                    test replications elapsed relative
## 3       cf_shallow(bgd)          100    3.47    1.000
## 4 cf_shallowstrict(bgd)          100    3.54    1.020
## 1             rfun(bgd)          100   11.28    3.251
## 2          cf_copy(bgd)          100   17.52    5.049
## 6 cf_structshallow(bgd)          100   51.51   14.844
## 5        cf_struct(bgd)          100   64.82   18.680
```

Comment: *"but Rcpp actually makes things slower when objects inside are larger"* -- at a glance, the likely cause of this is your conversion to `arma::` types. Any time you convert from an Rcpp type to, e.g. `arma::vec`, `arma::mat`, etc. a deep copy has to be performed, which can take a non-trivial amount of time for larger objects. Have you tested your claim using only Rcpp types?

Comment: Note that there are ways to instantiate arma objects _without copying_ which is what we do at the interface.  But @nrussell is spot on, that is the first thing for you to try.  Once you have that, try zero-cost arma conversion.

Comment: Sounds plausible. This minimal example easy to do in plain Rcpp, other code pieces that benefit from the ease of Armadillo are not. Dirk: any guidance on zero cost arma conversion?

Comment: Look at advanced constructors in arma docs; there are two boolean toggles promising to not alter dims, and reusing memory.

Comment: Thank you! This indeed speeds things up. The strict=true argument doesn't seem to have an impact, though. Any comments?

Comment: Sorry I don;t have time to do code review for you. We created a related [benchmark in RcppArmadillo](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/examples/fastLm.r), maybe you can start there.

Comment: Fair enough. I have cleaned up the post and also included the approach using structs. I wanted to look specifically look at nested lists and data access, but it really doesn't change things much. For those who want to use structs - any way to use shallow copies? Or should we just stay away from that?